# Timeout error when generating a large number of assets as once

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm running Hyperledger Composer v0.20.2, Hyperledger Fabric v1.2, on Ubuntu 16.04. I have a BNA installed and running through composer-rest-server. I am in a situation where I need to generate a large amount of assets (10,000 - 100,000) at a time.

The problem: when exceeding around the ~2000 mark, I am met with a timeout error:

> Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: failed to
>   execute transaction
>   734ddb8c7bb40df506066e212cd3a19aae1434bfbc8899929339e0827f47dc49:
>   error sending: timeout expired while executing transaction
>       at HLFConnection.invokeChainCode (/home/playground/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:1117:30)
>       at

I am wondering if there is a way to raise this timeout limit. From the searching that I have done, this timeout appears to be set on Hyperledger Fabric, not Composer.

Comment: have you tried changing BatchTimeout for orderer in Configtx.yaml in HL fabric? I'm not sure it will work but worth a try!

Comment: @Harshit I updated the BatchTimeout from 2s to 200s. But I am still getting the timeout error

Comment: have you tried changing value of  CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE in docker-compose.yml

Comment: I am editing /fabric-scripts/hlfv12/composer/docker-compose.yml but I am not seeing an option for CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE. The only similar setting I am seeing is CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL @Harshit

Comment: See answer in https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4597

Answer (score 0):

You will able to edit the maximum request size of the REST server by editing the `/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/server/config.json`.

**config.json :**

```
    "json": {
      "strict": false,
      "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "urlencoded": {
      "extended": true,
      "limit": "100kb"
    },
```

you have to increase the limit.

**Edited config.json:**

```
   "json": {
      "strict": false,
      "limit": "10000kb"
    },
    "urlencoded": {
      "extended": true,
      "limit": "10000kb"
    },
```

After Successfully edit you can install your BNA and run composer-rest-server.

Comment: When we were getting the maximum size limit error I did this change. While it did solve the size limit error, it didn't fix the timeout error.